# How to reduce the vertical whitespace between contiguous bullet points in MS PowerPoint

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, whitespace, bullets

Consider, as an example, the vertical whitespace between the first and second list element, i.e. their associated texts.
It'd like to reduce this whitespace.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the lines of bulleted text. Right-click and choose `Paragraph` from the context-menu. Change the Spacing values to something more preferable. Defaults are 10pt for Before, and 0pt for After.

[image]